# how to convert columns in a data.frame from list to a vector?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

```
mydat <- structure(list(A = list(0.0513386405422815, 0.0498556819169294), 
                        B = list(0.101635583229926, 0.108375425286815), 
                        C = list(0.0505800651643873, 0.0491970061885759), 
                        D = list(0.100497645341106, 0.107056699263229)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
> mydat$A
[[1]]
[1] 0.05133864

[[2]]
[1] 0.04985568
```

`mydat` is a data.frame, but its columns are all in `list` format. Is there a quick way to convert these to vectors instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
> out <- list2DF(Map(unlist, mydat))
> str(out)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ A: num  0.0513 0.0499
 $ B: num  0.102 0.108
 $ C: num  0.0506 0.0492
 $ D: num  0.1 0.107
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `unnest` all the columns in the dataframe.

```
library(tidyr)
mydat %>% unnest(cols = everything())

#     A     B      C     D
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 0.0513 0.102 0.0506 0.100
#2 0.0499 0.108 0.0492 0.107
```

Answer (score 1):

Just 'unlist()' them.

```
lapply(mydat, unlist)
$A
[1] 0.05133864 0.04985568

$B
[1] 0.1016356 0.1083754

$C
[1] 0.05058007 0.04919701

$D
[1] 0.1004976 0.1070567
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same vein as `apply()`-ing unlist, `apply()`-ing simplify2array:

```
# Simplify each list to a vector: 
data.frame(apply(mydat, 2, simplify2array))
```